# Mudança de Abas

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho um menu de abas que conforme vai selecionando as abas vai mudando o conteúdo.

Mudança das abas:

```
<script language="JavaScript">

function stAba(menu,conteudo)
{
  this.menu = menu;
  this.conteudo = conteudo;
}

var arAbas = new Array();
arAbas[0] = new stAba('td_usua','div_usua');
arAbas[1] = new stAba('td_empr','div_empr');
arAbas[2] = new stAba('td_nota','div_nota');
arAbas[3] = new stAba('td_soft','div_soft');

function AlternarAbas(menu,conteudo)
{
  for (i=0;i<arAbas.length;i++)
  {
   m = document.getElementById(arAbas[i].menu);
   m.className = 'menu';
   c = document.getElementById(arAbas[i].conteudo)
   c.style.display = 'none';
  }
  m = document.getElementById(menu)
  m.className = 'menu-sel';
  c = document.getElementById(conteudo)
  c.style.display = '';
}

</script>
```

A minha dúvida é: *"Como limpar os dados da aba anterior ao se selecionar outra aba?"*

Imagem do menu: [image: Menu com abas]

Chamo o `AlternarAbas()` no menu onde é escolhida a opção desejada:

```
<body onLoad="AlternarAbas('td_usua','div_usua')">
<table width="945" height="50"  align="left" valign="top" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" border="0" style="border-left: 1px solid #000000;" >
   <tr>
    <td height="20" width="50" class="menu" id="td_usua" onClick="AlternarAbas('td_usua','div_usua')">Usuario</td>
    <td height="20" width="50" class="menu" id="td_empr" onClick="AlternarAbas('td_empr','div_empr')">Empresa</td>
    <td height="20" width="50" class="menu" id="td_nota" onClick="AlternarAbas('td_nota','div_nota')">Nota Fiscal</td>
    <td height="20" width="50" class="menu" id="td_soft" onClick="AlternarAbas('td_soft','div_soft')">Software</td>
  </tr>
```

Os dados ao qual me refiro são os que o usuário digita. Ou seja, caso o usuário digite algo na área do `incluir do Usuário` e logo depois mudar para `Empresa`, os dados que ele informou no `incluir` sumirão!

imagem do incluir: [image: Incluir]

Funciona se for chamado por um iframe?

```
<tr>
    <td height="300" width="" class="tb-conteudo" colspan="4" align="left" valign="top" >  
        <div id="div_usua" class="conteudo" style="display: none; padding-top:5px;">
            <table align="left" border="0" width="2%">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <iframe style="border-radius:20px;" scrolling="no" src="../sai_cada_usua/menu_com_abas_usua.php" width="900" height="400 " >
                        </iframe>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>      
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para que possas alternar de aba e proceder à limpeza dos valores preenchidos no formulário via JavaScript, deverás fazer uso do método **[`reset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.reset)** que vai repor o formulário para os valores iniciais:

[Exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/SNxS4/1/)

## O teu código alterado

O teu código foi alterado para incluir um novo parâmetro que diz respeito ao formulário:

```
function stAba(menu,conteudo,formulario)
{
  this.menu = menu;
  this.conteudo = conteudo;
  this.formulario = formulario;
}

var arAbas = new Array();
arAbas[0] = new stAba('td_usua', 'div_usua', 'form_usua');
arAbas[1] = new stAba('td_empr', 'div_empr', 'form_empr');
arAbas[2] = new stAba('td_nota', 'div_nota', 'form_nota');
arAbas[3] = new stAba('td_soft', 'div_soft', 'form_soft');

function AlternarAbas(menu, conteudo, formulario)
{
  for (i=0;i<arAbas.length;i++)
  {
   m = document.getElementById(arAbas[i].menu);
   m.className = 'menu';
   c = document.getElementById(arAbas[i].conteudo)
   c.style.display = 'none';
   f = document.getElementById(arAbas[i].formulario);
   f.reset();
  }
  m = document.getElementById(menu)
  m.className = 'menu-sel';
  c = document.getElementById(conteudo)
  c.style.display = '';
}
```

A chamada passa a ser:

```
// O terceiro parâmetro é o ID for formulário alvo.
AlternarAbas('td_usua','div_usua', 'form_usua');
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda @Zuul era por isso mesmo que eu procurava! Mesmo não funcionando em meu código, eu decodifico ele para implementar. Mas a ideia era essa mesma que eu queria ^^